# Вывести измененный массив но не менять его

Tags: массивы, ruby

Есть массив числ. Нужно поменять местами минимальный и максимальный элементы.

```
a=[24, 2, 35, 595, 100, 4, 21]
```

Есть такой код:

```rb
a=[24, 2, 35, 595, 100, 4, 21]
a[a.index(a.min)], a[a.index(a.max)] = a[a.index(a.max)], a[a.index(a.min)]
puts a
```

Но мне нужно вывести измененный массив, но что бы сам массив оставался без изменений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему вы просто не скопируете массив?

```ruby
original = [24, 2, 35, 595, 100, 4, 21]
a = original.dup
max = a.index(a.max)
min = a.index(a.min)
a[min], a[max] = a[max], a[min]
```

Answer (score 0):

В чём проблема? Просто перед тем, как изменить массив выведи его, раз тебе не требуется вывод с изменениями

Comment: Нужно вывести изменный массив (где минимальный и максимальный элемент поменялись местами) но нужно что бы сам массив оставался без изменений.

Comment: С массивом это будет сделать труднее, чем с чем-то на подобии динамических шаблонов из библиотеки STL в ЯП C++, но всё равно допустимо. Раз тебе нельзя менять первый массив, заведи второй и в нём присвой всем элементам то же значение, что было в первом, но макс и мин элемент поменяй местами. После выведи этот 2 массив